# Communication in wireless sensor network using nesC

Tags: wireless, nesc

I have a base station and a sensor node. I want to establish communication between these two. The base station should poll the sensor node requesting temperature data captured by the sensor node. The sensor node replies with the temperature data to the base station. I can confirm that the base station and sensor node are in relative proximity to send/receive the data.

I want to write a code in nesC which can programmatically do this. Where can I find a good guide to do this?

**Specifications:**

- Sensors- MTS400
- Programming board- MIB520
- Mote: Iris

Answer (score 1):

You can read the TinyOS tutorials about various subjects here:
http://tinyos.stanford.edu/tinyos-wiki/index.php/TinyOS_Tutorials

Oscilloscope is an example application included in TinyOS distribution that performs what you are trying to do. You can read the code in `apps/Oscilloscope`.
See also some help on installing and using Oscilloscope [here](http://tinyos.stanford.edu/tinyos-wiki/index.php/Quickstart%3a_TelosB#Oscilloscope_Application%3a_BaseStation_.26_Sensor_Testing):